# Is it possible to pull comments from facebook into your blog?

Tags: comments, facebook

I have a client who wants to be able to share his latest blog posts on Facebook (no problem there) but then he wants the comments made on his Facebook page to that share shown on his blog as part of the comments on the blog post.

I have been digging around and while I can find ways to let users comment on your blog using Facebook's api (http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/198) I can find nothing that pulls comments from Facebook to display on your site.

The closest I could come is this http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/facebook-comments/ which according to its developer is broken and can only be fixed by 'screen scraping' Facebook which, of course, is against Facebooks TOS.

Does anyone know if there is a working plugin, or a relatively simple method to get this done?

Answer (score 4):

I just added this feature to the [beta branch](http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/simple-facebook-connect/branches/new-sfc/) of [Simple Facebook Connect](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/simple-facebook-connect/). It pulls comments back from auto-published stories and integrates them into the normal comments stream.

Features:

- Integrated with Auto-Publish. When you post, and it's auto-published to your Page or Profile, SFC notices and saves the resulting story IDs for later polling.
- Fast. Every 6 hours (maximum), comments are pulled from Facebook and cached locally. Comments are only pulled when needed, if nobody's looking at old posts, then FB comments are not pulled for it.
- The comments are added to the normal comments listing.
- FB Avatars are displayed for them.
- A "facebook" class is added to these comments for separate styling.
- Works with user comments or "Page" comments.

TODO List for this:

- Add a link back to the FB comment so people can reply there instead

You can get the current (mostly working) beta of SFC here: http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/simple-facebook-connect/branches/new-sfc/

Answer (score 3):

Try [simple facebook connect](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/simple-facebook-connect/) from @Otto. It's well coded and offers tons of sub-plugins to extend.

Answer (score 1):

You can use, [WordBooker](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordbooker/), [WPBook](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wpbook/) or [Facebook CommentsTNG](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/facebook-commentstng/)

Comment: Actually neither of these plugins do what I am after. WPBook is buggy and poorly coded. Facebook Comments TNG only works with Facebook Notes. After doing more digging I am convinced that at present this is not actually possible to achieve (though I would really love to be proven wrong!)

Comment: There is WordBooker (which I used on my blog months ago). See link in my answer.

Comment: Wordbooker doesn't do it either

Comment: Maybe I don't understand what you want exactly? When I look at the description of the plugin you provided in your question "Facebook comments is a WordPress plugin that will import comments from your facebook notes back into your wordpress blog.", isn't Facebook CommentsTNG doing the same? "Facebook CommentsTNG will pull your comments from imported Facebook Notes back into your blog."

Comment: Yes, and I don't want to pull comments from Facebook Notes. I am talking about cross posting from your blog to a facebook wall and having comments from both sides present on both sides. Ensuring that regardless of where the conversation happens, the whole conversation is there for everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Wordbooker absolutely does this. You just have to configure it to do so. I use it on my blog. Every time I post a new blog entry it creates a status update on my Facebook. Any comments to that Facebook entry in turn get added to the comments of the blog post.

See this post on my blog (The very first comment came from Facebook, as you can see by hovering your mouse of the commenters name): http://dracore.com/?p=150

Make sure 'Import Comments from Facebook for Wordbook Posts' is checked in Wordbooker settings:

Comment: agreed on wordbooker - i use it seemlessly to pull comments mad on facebook into my blog...

Answer (score 0):

There is a plugin called "FB Comments Importer" that is specialized for this thing. Its PRO version has some advanced features to import from groups, profiles, from images and from statuses, to autoimport via cron, etc...

The other plugins i tried didnt work for me.

FB Comments Importer: http://wordpress.org/plugins/fb-comments-importer/